# Unable to add Exchange 2010 account to Outlook 2011

Tags: macos, ms-office, exchange-activesync

I have a user who is trying to setup Outlook 2011 with his Exchange 2010 mailbox/account. When entering the details for the account Outlook 'freezes'.

[This is the window it freezes at.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbt0G.png)

I have tried different accounts on the same server and they don't work either. This is a fresh install of Office 2011 that is up-to-date with the latest patches. The OS is Lion that is also up-to-date.

There are other Macs on the same network that can connect add the same account into Outlook, seems to be just this Mac facing the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check the Console logs on that machine for MS Office? If there is not specific log for Office, can you attempt configuring the account with Console open and take note of any logs related to MS Office? I'd be interested to see what is happening on the back end.